# Do i need a switch between TP4056 and 5V step up module?

Tags: circuit-design

Is it necessary to put a switch in between? Picture example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhXKu.jpg)

i presume not still dont want my smoke alarm to trip if im wrong, its better to ask :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the picture you've included depicts a module which has the step-up regulator connected to the charge output of the TP4056 i.e. the place where a Li-ion battery should be. What's the purpose of this? Anything that can power the charging module can probably power the step-up regulator (boost converter) as well. Your explanation will probably determine whether a switch is necessary or not (and if not, what other options are there).

Comment: Its not my picture. The Li Ion battery is behind the board. The loop is closed.

Comment:  So why don't you put up a drawing (consisting e.g. of the two boards plus wiring between them with all the wires marked accordingly) and an explanation of what is it that you're actually trying to do?